# A question about the onSubmit function in the react application standing on the node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I just started learning React and I have a question about my app. It is about the onSubmit function located in the formic. The point is that when I open the application on the local server, I go to the http: // localhost: 3001 / employees route, the onSubmit function works and displays values to me. But when I open it on node.js, after clicking the button, it becomes inactive and nothing happens. Same onClick function shows me nothing.

App.jsx

```
 import "./App.css";
 import EditEmployee from "./EditEmployee";
 import EmployeeList from "./InternList";
 import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
   return (
   <div className="App">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/employees/:id" element={<EditEmployee/>} />
    <Route path="/" element={<EmployeeList />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
 );
 }

  export default App;
```

EditEmployee.jsx

```
 import React, {useState } from 'react';
 import { useParams } from 'react-router';
 import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
 import { Formik } from 'formik';



const  EditEmployee = () => {
const { id } = useParams();
const [Employee, setEmployee] = useState(0);
    const fetchEmployee = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/employees/${id}`);
        const Employee = await response.json();
        setEmployee(Employee)
    }
    fetchEmployee();



    return (
    <div>
        <NavLink to="/">Back to list </NavLink>
  <Formik
    validateOnhange={false}
    validateOnBlur={false}
   initialValues={{ id: id, name: '', email: ''}}
   validate={values => {
     const errors = {};
     if (!values.name)
     {
       errors.name = <a>Required name</a>
     }
     if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email)) 
     {
       errors.email = <a>Invalid email address</a>
     }
   
     return errors;
   }}
   onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 400);
   }}
 >
   {({
     values,
     errors,
     handleChange,
     handleBlur,
     handleSubmit,
     isSubmitting,
   }) => (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       {errors.name}
       <input 
         type="text"
         name="name"
         onChange={handleChange}
         onBlur={handleBlur}
         value={values.name}
       />
       {errors.email}
       <input
         type="email"
         name="email"
         onChange={handleChange}
         onBlur={handleBlur}
         value={values.email}
         
       />
       <button type="submit"  disabled={isSubmitting}  
        onClick={() => { alert("Saving reports in demo mode is not 
   available")}}>Submit</button>
     </form>
   )}
 </Formik>
    </div>
  );
 };

 export default EditEmployee;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');





app.use(bodyparser.json());


  app.use(express.static (path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
  app.get('*', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
   })

  app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

the button is Inactive becuase you make it inactive here

```
<button type="submit"  disabled={isSubmitting}  
        onClick={() => { alert("Saving reports in demo mode is not 
   available")}}>Submit</button>
```

You might want to do this

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => { alert("Saving reports in demo mode is not available")}}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Like I said, everything works fine when I run applications on the local server. On node.js, when I open the application, onSubmit does not work, the same goes for css styles.